# How to combine listing and figure into a single figure?

Tags: floats, listings

I am using package `listings`, and I would like to combine a `listing` and a `figure` into a single float. As an example, I am using `listings` as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML,float=h,label=lst:transition_selector_example, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,tabsize=2,
  caption={Example SCXML document used to illustrate transition selection optimization strategies}]
<scxml>
    <state id="A">
        <transition target="B" event="e1" id="transition1"/>
        <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition2"/>
        <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition3"/>
    </state>
    <state id="B">
        <transition target="A" event="e3" id="transition4"/>
    </state>
</scxml>
\end{lstlisting}
```

Later, I have a figure with an `\includegraphics` in it, like the following:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{chapters/3/figures/firefox-transitionSelector}
\caption{Results of Transition Selection optimization strategy in Firefox}
\label{fig:firefox-transitionSelector}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to make the listing become a part of that figure, such that it share's the figure's reference number, and is laid out in the page as a single combined graphical entity.

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance anyone can offer regarding how to do this.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

`listings` and `\includegraphics` can each be included essentially anywhere.
The following puts them one above the other, side by side layout is also possible if you put the listing into a minipage of a width that allows the graphic to the side.

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{chapters/3/figures/firefox-transitionSelector}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML,float=h,label=lst:transition_selector_example,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,tabsize=2,caption={Example SCXML document used to illustrate transition selection optimization strategies}]
<scxml>
    <state id="A">
        <transition target="B" event="e1" id="transition1"/>
        <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition2"/>
        <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition3"/>
    </state>
    <state id="B">
        <transition target="A" event="e3" id="transition4"/>
    </state>
</scxml>
\end{lstlisting}

\caption{Results of Transition Selection optimization strategy in Firefox}
\label{fig:firefox-transitionSelector}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to David's answer (in case you want "subcaptions"):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}[%
            language=XML,%
            label=lst:transition_selector_example,%
            basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
            tabsize=2
        ]
        <scxml>
            <state id="A">
                <transition target="B" event="e1" id="transition1"/>
                <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition2"/>
                <transition target="B" event="e2" id="transition3"/>
            </state>
            <state id="B">
                <transition target="A" event="e3" id="transition4"/>
            </state>
        </scxml>
        \end{lstlisting}
        \subcaption{Example SCXML document used to illustrate\ldots}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{2em}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{chapters/3/figures/firefox-transitionSelector}
    \subcaption{A screenshot (??)}
    \end{subfigure}
    \label{fig:firefox-transitionSelector}
    \caption{Results of Transition Selection optimization strategy in Firefox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```